# get pixel position of pointer

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to get the cursor position in pixel value, using the standard Python libraries?

I can not properly position the popup menu:

```
    pos = self.text.GetLastPosition()
    start, end = self.text.PositionToXY(pos)

    self.text.PopupMenuXY(self.popupmenu,start, end)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not with a *standard* python library as that is platform dependant. On Windows you can use winapi:

```
import win32api
x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
```

And on Linux you can use xlib:

```
from Xlib.display import Display   
display = Display()
coord = display.screen().root.query_pointer()._data
x = coord["root_x"]
y = coord["root_y"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the mouse position with wxPython, you can use:

```
pos = wx.GetMousePosition() # in screen coordinates
```

That gives you the XY position in screen coordinates as a tuple.
If you need the position relative to a widget, you have to convert it to client coordinates by calling ScreenToClient() on the widget.

```
pos = self.textctrl.ScreenToClient(pos) # relative to textctrl
```

If you just want to display a popup menu at the current mouse position, you can skip this and call PopupMenu() without supplying a position:

```
self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu) # pop up menu at mouse position
```